# Prove of inner product space and orthonormal system's necessary condition to be complete

Tags: inner-products, orthonormal

[image]

I have no idea how to start, anything would help, thank you!

Comment: Well, this is not beginners linear algebra: surely you must have done something already, uh?

Comment: I know that it is complete when every Cauchy sequence in Y converges. I don't see any sequences in this problem other than the {u_i}. Also that it is orthonormal if <ui,uj> = 0 if i does not equal to j. But I don't see how completeness have to do with this problem

Comment: I think I understood this question wrong... I think I am suppose to prove that there are zeros in Y which is orthogonal to u_i? Am I correct? (is no non zero saying there is zero?)

Comment: I think you're confusing complete *metric* space and complete orthonormal *set* in an inner product space, @JustAsk...

Comment: Yes, I was confused about that. So since I know {u_i} is an orthonormal basis  of Y, and Y has an orthonomral basis, shouldn't it automatically be complete by theorem "Any complete inner product space V has an orthonormal basis"?

Comment: Nobody is telling you $\;\{u_i\}\;$ is a basis **but** an orthonormal system...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the system is complete and there exists $\;v\in Y\;\;s.t.\;\;v\perp u_i\;\;\forall\,i\;$. Then

$$v=\sum_{i\in I} a_iu_i\implies \forall\,k\;,\;\;0=\langle v,u_k\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i\in I}a_iu_i\,,\, u_k\right\rangle=\sum_{i\in I}a_i\langle u_i,u_k\rangle=a_k$$

and from here $\;v=0\;$